# How to analyze performance on Chrome for Android?

Tags: android, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-for-android

Is it possible to show some kind of frame counter or GPU meter on my Android device? I'd like to test and see how small changes impact the FPS rate. Remote debugging isn't an option because it severely reduces the performance (at least on my end).

Note that I am not trying to profile a native Android app, just a website that heavily uses JavaScript and CSS hardware acceleration.

Comment: So this isn't sufficient? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings

Comment: @MorrisonChang That has nothing to do with Android

Comment: Actually this would have been a better link http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/03/frame-rate-hud-on-chrome-for-android.html  but it looks like in recent versions of Chrome the FPS counter flag been disabled. I assume you've seen this: http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/profile-gpu-rendering/index.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang No I haven't seen that before, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @MorrisonChang It's been a while, but if you convert your comment to an answer I will gladly accept it.